# How to filter List<T> and find average to make a distinct List<T>

Tags: c#

How can I filter a list into distinct values by a specific field and where the values weren’t distinct take their averages. Please see example

```
{
Public int Time;
Public float Voltage;
Public float Current;
Public Resistance(int time, float voltage, float current)
{
Time = time;
Voltage = voltage;
Current = current;
}
Public List<Resistance> _resistances = new List<Resistance>();
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time = 1, Voltage =3.2, Current = 1);
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time = 1, Voltage =4.0, Current = 2);
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time = 1, Voltage =6.5, Current = 6);
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time = 2, Voltage =3.2, Current =4);
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time =2, Voltage =3.2, Current = 2);
_resistances.Add(new Resistance(Time = 3, Voltage 5, Current = 1);
```

Aim is to have a list with:

```
_resistance[0]{ Time =1,, Voltage = Average(3.2,4,6.5), Current = Average(1,2,6))
_resistance[1]{ Time =2,, Voltage = Average(3.2,3.2,5), Current = Average(4,2,1))
}
```

For any arbitrary values and quantity of entries

I have tried the following

```
            int divisor = 1;
            double voltageSum = 0;
            double currentSum = 0;

            while (j >= 1)
            {
                while (_resistances[j].Time== _resistances[j - 1].Time)
                {
                    divisor++;
                    voltageSum += _resistances[j].Voltage;
                    currrentSum += _resistances[j].Current;
                    _resistances.RemoveAt(j);
                    j -= 1;
                }

                var averageVoltage = voltageSum / divisor;
                var averageCurrent = currentSum / divisor;
                _rawDataList[j].Voltage = (float)averageVoltage;
                _rawDataList[j].Current= (float)averageCurrent;
                j -= 1;
            }
```

I know this is wrong but I cant seem to figure out the logic to modifying a list, I think creating a new list and appending in a forloop maybe the way forward but I cant work it out. I think Linq may help, but not too experienced with Lambda expressions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the [Average](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-average/) linq method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Comment: You are asking 2 questions in one: about Distinct() and Average(). Please solve one problem at a time.

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes I have but I require the average of all values where the Times are equal. I can average by Voltage or Current separately but I need to average all values where only the times are equal and append to a list. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if Russ posts one question about Distinct() and one question about Average(), both will be immediately closed by the community for being overly trivial. I also don't really see this as two distinct questions, Russ is trying to accomplish one thing.

Comment: @pep: I'm trying to accomplish one thing: program a CRM. If I post that as a question, you would implement it for me? Certainly now. I can break it down into single problems, each of which is overly trivial. Same for Russ. Instead of solving many problems at once, he should a) learn that when he says "distinct", that's the wrong term b) learn what distinct is c) learn what he wants instead d) learn how to calculate an average on his own e) learn how to use a pre-made average function.

Comment: Ok come on now. “Program a CRM” is a massively larger, broader, and less specific scope. It’s not comparable *at all* to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using Linq, group your records by Time and use the `Average` function to compute the values for Voltage and Current for the Time groups:

```
_resistances
 .GroupBy(r => r.Time)
 .Select(g => new { 
      Time = g.Key, 
      Voltage = g.Average(r => r.Voltage), 
      Current = g.Average(r => r.Current) 
 });
```

Comment: Oh perfect thank you Jcruz, hope this wasn't a daft question.

Comment: @Russ No daft question, just another case where Linq makes things easier